# How to get data in ViewModel from database and show it to view in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating a voting system same as StackOverflow. I have two types of voting class `UpVote` and `DownVote` and those have navigation property to `Post` class. So my issue is I am able to do ajax calling and able to store `Upvote` and `DownVote` for logged-in users. 
But when I am trying to see those votes through another user account its shows zero votes. I checked my `database` and there are votes in `UpVote` and `DownVote` tables.
So I am stuck now How to show that data through my `QuestionDetailViewModel` to `View` and how to keep it to show every other user.
I am new to asp.net please guide me on how to solve these issues.
Here is my `Post` Domain Model

```
 public class Post
    {
        public Post()
        {
            UpVotes = new HashSet<UpVotes>();
            DownVotes = new HashSet<DownVotes>();
        }
        public int PostId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CreatedById { get; set; }

        public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public int Views { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<UpVotes> UpVotes { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<DownVotes> DownVotes { get; set; }
    }
```

And here are my `UpVote` and `DownVote` domain models

```
public class UpVotes
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime VotedDateTime { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int PostId { get; set; }

        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }

    }

public class DownVotes
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime VotedDateTime { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int PostId { get; set; }

        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is my api `Controller` for handling the `Upvote` and `DownVote`

```
[HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult UpVote(int id)
        {
            var user = _context.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            var post = _context.Posts.Find(id);
            var upVotes = post.UpVotes.ToList();
            var downVotes = post.DownVotes.ToList();

            if (upVotes.FindAll(u => u.UserId == user.Id).Count == 0)
            {
                if (downVotes.Select(u => u.UserId).Contains(user.Id))
                {
                    var downVote = _context.DownVotes.Where(u => u.UserId == user.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    _context.DownVotes.Remove(downVote);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
                UpVotes upVote = new UpVotes
                {
                    VotedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                    UserId = user.Id,
                    User = user,
                    Post = post,
                    PostId = id,
                };
                post.UpVotes.Add(upVote);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return Ok();                
            }
            return BadRequest();
        }

        public IHttpActionResult DownVote(int id)
        {

            var user = _context.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            var post = _context.Posts.Find(id);
            var downVotes = post.DownVotes.ToList();
            var upVotes = post.UpVotes.ToList();

            if (downVotes.FindAll(u => u.UserId == user.Id).Count == 0)
            {
                if (upVotes.Select(u => u.UserId).Contains(user.Id))
                {
                    var upVote = _context.UpVotes.Where(u => u.UserId == user.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    _context.UpVotes.Remove(upVote);
                }
                DownVotes downVote = new DownVotes
                {
                    VotedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                    UserId = user.Id,
                    User = user,
                    Post = post,
                    PostId = id,
                };
                post.DownVotes.Add(downVote);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return Ok();
            }
            return BadRequest();
        }
```

Here is my `ViewModel`

```
public class QuestionDetailViewModel
    {
        ApplicationDbContext _context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        public virtual Question question { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Add your answer.")]
        public string AnswerContent { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public int QuestionId { get; set; }

        public int AnswerId { get; set; }
        public int VoteCount 
        {
            get { return this.question.Post.UpVotes.Count - this.question.Post.DownVotes.Count; }
        }
    }
```

And here is my `View`

```
@model AskMe.Models.ViewModel.QuestionDetailViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "QuestionDetails";
}

<h1>Question Details: </h1>
<h3>@Model.question.Post.Title</h3>
@Html.Raw(Model.question.Post.Content)
<hr />
<h3>Answers:</h3>
<div id="paginationContainer">
    @foreach (var answer in Model.question.Answers)
    {
        <div class="card bg-light m-1">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Answered by: @answer.Post.CreatedBy.UserName</h5>
                @Html.Raw(answer.Post.Content)
            </div>
            <div id="vote" class="col">
                <div>
                    <button data-vote-id="@answer.Post.PostId" class="nav-link thumbs-up" href=""><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
                <div id="Count">
                    @Model.VoteCount
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button data-vote-id="@answer.Post.PostId" class="nav-link thumbs-down" href=""><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            @Html.ActionLink("View Comments", "Index", "Comments", new { answerId = answer.PostId }, null) |
        </div>
    }
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h3>Contribute your answer: </h3>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AnswerContent, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.AnswerContent, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.QuestionId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.question)
                <input type="submit" value="Contribute now" class="btn btn-outline-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval");

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            tinyMCE.init({
                mode: "textareas",
            });
            $('#paginationContainer').buzinaPagination({
                itemsOnPage: 3,
                prevnext: true,
                prevText: "Previous",
                nextText: "Next"
            });

            $("#vote").on("click", ".thumbs-up", function () {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/api/votes/upvote/" + $(this).attr("data-vote-id"),
                    method: "POST",
                    success: function () {
                        var countTxt = $("#Count").text();
                        console.log(countTxt);
                        var count = parseInt(countTxt);
                        $("#Count").text(count + 1);
                        console.log(count);
                    }
                })
            })

            $("#vote").on("click", ".thumbs-down", function () {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/api/votes/downvote/" + $(this).attr("data-vote-id"),
                    method: "POST",
                    success: function () {
                        var countTxt = $("#Count").text();
                        console.log(countTxt);
                        var count = parseInt(countTxt);
                        $("#Count").text(count - 1);
                        console.log(count);
                    }
                })
            })
        });
    </script>
}
```

I believe, I messed up with my `ViewModel` but I am not sure how to get data of votes from the `database` to ViewModel and do the arithmetic operation to get total votes in `ViewModel` or view. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it's only about getting and showing data that's in the database it's enough to show that code only.

Comment: @GertArnold In my viewmodel property `VoteCount` when I check in debugging it shows zero for other logged-in user. I dont know how get data from my `upvote` and `downvote` tables to count difference between votes.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].